# Android app https deeplink and Chrome browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, deep-linking

I have implemented https deeplinking in my Android app following the [Google guidelines](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app).

It is working almost fine, when user opens Chrome browser, searches something related to *mycompany* and clicks on a link, the OS will prompt to select between my app or the browser. Also, if someone sends the link by mail or a messenger app, if the user clicks on it, the OS will also prompt to select between app/browser.

However, I see the following problems:

1. If the user opens Chrome and types in the address bar: *www.mycompany.com*, OS will not prompt to select between app/browser, it will just open it in the browser.
2. Once the user is in the browser navigating the home webpage of www.mycompany.com when it clicks a link that the app handles (eg. https://www.mycompany.com/product/1234) OS **WILL NOT** prompt to select between the app and the browser.
3. The worst problem is: if the user clicks a link that the app does not handle (eg. https://www.mycompany.com/not-handled-path), it will open the corresponding webpage as expected, but then in this webpage if the user clicks on a link handled by the app (eg. https://www.mycompany.com/product/1234) OS **WILL** prompt to select between app/browser.

As you can see it seems the behavior is not consistent.
I would say that the expected behavior is to always prompt to decide between the app/browser or always let the user navigate through the website.

Please, let me know if I misunderstood anything, any advice is welcome.

This is the intent filter that is handled by my dispatching activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="https"/>
    <data android:host="www.mycompany.com"/>
    <data android:pathPattern="/" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/product.*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/list.*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/stores.*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/brands.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

In summary this is the inconsistency:

Writing the address www.mycompany.com enters to home webpage. This webpage has a link to https://www.mycompany.com/product/123, clicking it enters to product detail webpage (OS does not prompt to open in app or browser).

Writing the address www.mycompany.com/not-handled-path enters to webpage, then this webpage has also a link to https://www.mycompany.com/product/123, clicking it, however, to my surprise OS DOES prompt to open in app or browser.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem while working on my app and did not find any documentation which clearly states the expected behavior. Then I dig into [chromium source](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/externalnav/ExternalNavigationHandler.java?q=browser_fallback_url&sq=package:chromium&l=385) to figure out what is happening. As per chrome implementation when navigating within the same host it will show an Intent App Chooser if there is a newer App available to handle the target url as compared to the apps which can handle the source/referrer url.

In light of above the explanation for what you see is as follows:

1. User explicity chose browser to view your website and to honor this chrome has put a specific check in the code
2. You are navigating from a handled-in-app-url to another handled-in-app-url, hence no OS pop-up
3. You are navigating from a not-handled-in-app-url to a handled-in-app-url. Chrome will see there is a newer app which can handle the target url as compared to the apps that handle older url and hence it shows the OS pop-up to let the user decide.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, the behaviour you have is as expected.
1) You ask your browser to open a site. If you ask the OS will let you choose between browser and app, but you asked the browser.

2) I used it whis way and it worked fine.

3) I dont see any problems with that. The OS have only one option to open it, so it use the browser. If you find it ackward, handle the unhandled link.

Comment: Ok, but why sometimes clicking on the same hyperlink handled by the app the OS prompts (bullet 2) and sometimes not (bullet 3)? This seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: I've just reaslized. Try change  <data android:pathPattern="/product.*" /> to  <data android:pathPattern="/product" />. Maybe the dot is the issue.

Comment: Try with other browser.

Comment: I have tried with native browser. OS always prompts to select between app/browser.